# How to change text line with Bash/Shell programming?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

i am trying to build a Bash file.

one of the commands is:

```
sudo vi /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

How can i change Automaticaly this text line :

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```

with this text line:

```
server.host: "localhost"
```

tnx

Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware, untested!

```
sed -ri .bak '/server.host:/s/: *"[^"]*"/: "localhost"/' /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

To test it run it without `-i .bak` and the change is output on stdout instead of changing the file. `-i .bak` causes in-place editing and the creation of a backup file.

Comment: it had worked this way: sudo sed -i -e '/server.host:/s/: *"[^"]*"/: "localhost"/' /opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml

Comment: I picked the arguments for GNU sed. Apparently you're using a different one.

Answer (score 1):

you can search and replace text from within the vi text editor using the following command

> :%s/0.0.0.0/localhost/

[more info](http://www.linfo.org/vi/search.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following commands

> [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

or

> [awk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)